# Extracting licenses of dependencies from maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a maven plugin that prints the licenses of all the project's dependencies.
For that, I wrote a method that uses maven to fetch the model of each dependency.

```java
public Model readModel(final String artifactId, final String groupId, final String version)
        throws ProjectBuildingException {
    final var artifact = this.repositorySystem.createProjectArtifact(groupId, artifactId, version);
    final ProjectBuildingResult build = this.mavenProjectBuilder.build(artifact,
            this.session.getProjectBuildingRequest());
    return build.getProject().getModel();
}
```

Later in my code, I pick the license from the model.

The `repositorySystem` is injected into the mojo via:

```java
@Component
RepositorySystem repositorySystem;
```

The issue with that code is, that it only works with dependencies that are available on maven central.
For other dependencies, it fails with:

```
Error resolving project artifact: Failure to find com.exasol:exasol-jdbc:pom:7.0.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced for project com.exasol:exasol-jdbc:pom:7.0.4
```

Is there something that I missed? I would expect that this `repositorySystem` uses the same repositories like maven itself that are configured in the `pom.xml`.

Is this the right way to solve the problem? (I'm also not happy with having the dependency injection, but could not find a way to solve this without it)

Comment: You do not want to use https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/ ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the license-maven-plugin does not provide a machine-readable list of all dependencies with their licenses. Parsing the generated report seemed too unstable to me.

Comment: `license:download-licenses` creates an XML file with the dependencies and their licenses. What else do you want?

Comment: you're right. Maybe it's even a better solution than doing it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution:

```java
@Override
    public Model readModel(final String artifactId, final String groupId, final String version)
            throws ProjectBuildingException {
    final Artifact artifactDescription = this.repositorySystem.createProjectArtifact(groupId, artifactId, version);
    final ProjectBuildingRequest projectBuildingRequest = this.session.getProjectBuildingRequest();
    projectBuildingRequest.setRemoteRepositories(this.mvnProject.getRemoteArtifactRepositories());
    final ProjectBuildingResult build = this.mavenProjectBuilder.build(artifactDescription, projectBuildingRequest);
    return build.getProject().getModel();
}
```

The trick was to remove the `this.repositorySystem.createProjectArtifact` which turned out to be overhead anyway and add the repositories of the project to the `ProjectBuildingResult`.

Comment: I am looking for similar case. I want to get details of license of an dependency. Can I achieve this using java code? In above code, can you explain what is this.session, this.mvnProject, this.mavenProjectBuilder? Also, I tried license:download-licenses, but it downloads licenses which I do not want.